# Removing Data Access layer coupling from user interface

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

Currently my application's UI layer is coupled to my DAL dll. Dal is initialized like this:

```
//Initialize Data Access for AS400
Dal = JDE8Dal.Instance;
Dal.conString = Properties.Settings.Default.conAS400;
```

DAL is desinged as singleton. I thought that forcing the application to have one instance is a good idea.

DAL:

```
public class JDE8Dal
    {
        public string conString { get; set; }
        private static readonly JDE8Dal _instance = new JDE8Dal();
        private JDE8Dal()
        {
        }
        public static JDE8Dal Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }
        // Methods
    }
```

My BLL will look something like this:

```
namespace YLA.Barcode
{
    public static class YlaBarcodeUtil
    {
        public static string LotStripZeroes(string str)
        {
            var ret = str;
            if (str.Trim().StartsWith("00"))
            {
                ret = YlaGeneralUtilities.StripLeadingNumofChars(str, 2);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

public class BarcodeBLL
{
    //DAL INIT HERE?
}
}
```

Now that i need to build more applications i need to move into a 3 layer architecture and start reading on DDD.

1) How to move the DAL handling in BLL? Just add the initialization in my BLL section?

2) Should i keep my DAL design as singleton or not?

Comment: I suggest you start reading on DDD before trying to come up with an implementation. In particular, the blue book and DDD Quickly have a chapter on layered architecture that might be of some help. Investigating on Repositories might be a good idea too.

Comment: @guillaume31 Am i really forced towards ioc? i mean the specific dal is not gonna change because change means new ERP and new erp means complete redesign. So i thought that IoC is not a must in my case

Comment: Depending on the size and complexity of your application, IoC/DI can be a must have if you want to test your code properly. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Inversion of Control pattern to reduce the dependency between your layers. In your case I would use a constructor injection as the data context is required by your class:

```
public class BarcodeBLL
{
    private JDE8Dal _context;

    public BarcodeBLL(JDE8Dal context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Data context should be short lived objects. If you're developing a web application you should instantiate one data context per request. I would also recommend using an ORM (Entity Framework / NHibernate).

Comment: When you say short lived what exactly you mean?. My dal methods are opening late the connection and each of them is closing it as soon as possible. I sould also dispose of the dal object in every bll method operation?

Comment: As short lived as possible. To complete a logical operation for example. ORM are caching data, if you keep them alive for a long time your local cache will be in a different state than the database and you'll end up with conflicts when committing the changes.

Comment: And where i would create my JDE8Dal context? to pass it here? I cant do it in my UI. I should do it where? in DAL class? How? can you elaborate?

Comment: The IoC container will create it for you and inject it in your BarcodeBLL class via the constructor. I would recommend you to read more on the Inversion of Control pattern (Google is your friend :)). One of the container you can use is Ninject: http://www.ninject.org/

Answer (score 0):

1: Normally you ahve a infrastructure layer that does the composition.

2: NO BY ALL MEANS. This is bordering "learn programming". Use a IOC container.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize Data Access for AS400
Dal = JDE8Dal.Instance;
Dal.conString = Properties.Settings.Default.conAS400;
```

That comment is misleading. This code doesn't actually initialize data access but only sets the database connection string. This should be done in the DAL itself and not in the UI.

```
public class JDE8Dal
    {
        public string conString { get; set; }
        private static readonly JDE8Dal _instance = new JDE8Dal();
        private JDE8Dal()
        {
        }
        public static JDE8Dal Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }
        // Methods
    }
```

Layers aren't usually defined this way, the DAL is an assembly/dll, not a class. As you wrote it, it seems like you want a God Object where all persistence logic is defined. Classes in the Data Access Layer are much more fine grained and specialized : for instance Repositories/DAO's manage persistence of one particular domain object.

In addition, it's generally [not a good idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx) to resort to a Singleton "just because it feels right to have only one instance". And especially not a mutable singleton. In your example, anyone can change `Dal.Instance.conString`, with potentially dramatic consequences on other consumers of the singleton. Among other drawbacks.

Even if there's likely to ever be one implementation of your DAL (AS400 as it seems), it's a good idea in projects of reasonable complexity to use dependency injection for unit testing purposes. DI enables you to easily substitute your concrete DAL object implementations for fake DAL objects that are much more lightweight and useful in unit tests.

```
public class BarcodeBLL
{
    //DAL INIT HERE?
}
```

Non, no DAL init here ;)

The business logic layer (Domain layer in DDD) shouldn't have a reference to the DAL, the DAL should have a reference to the BLL. A domain object shouldn't know how to persist itself (Persistence Ignorance principle) because it would have too many responsibilities (Single Responsibility Principle) and that would create a tight coupling between the BLL and the DAL, making it very awkward to reuse and maintain the BLL.

Comment: I got the points regarding the singleton and the DI purpose. what i really dont get is your last thought that DAL should have a reference to BLL and not the other way around. If i want to have a CheckLotValid logic in BLL that requires 2-3 dal methods to run and return data how i am gonna do it if i dont create my dal object in BLL?

Comment: DDD takes as a given that all business logic is in the Domain layer. You only turn to the DAL when you want to hydrate objects from the database or persist them, and this is often done in the Application layer or as part of an ORM tool's job. However if the Domain layer really needs to access the DAL, say a Repository for instance, you can always inject the concrete Repository into the Domain object, thus keeping a loose coupling between BLL and DAL.